# linkedin public profile url memberdata plugin

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to create a company directory which will provide a link to an employees linkedin public profile, if the uses chooses to connect.

So on our employee profile page, the user can choose to link their linkedin account to their employee profile.  We initiate an oAuth process and we retrieve their hashed linkedin id, which we then store. Great.  Now the part that isn't working.

Based on their plugin example, i have this...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: xxxxxxxxxxxx
    authorize: false
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function INTEST() {
        IN.API.Profile().ids("pU-LBvD_y0")
            .fields(['id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'picture-url', 'public-profile-url'])
            .result(function (result) {
                profile = result.values[0];
             })
             .error(function (errorResult) {
        var i = 0;
        });;
    }
</script>
```

I receive all information except the public-profile-url.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you have this figured out by now. But for the benefit of others:

When using the JavaScript API you must convert the profile field names from the dashed notation to studly caps. For example first-name becomes firstName.  public-profile-url becomes publicProfileUrl

Reference the following API documentation at
http://developer.linkedinlabs.com/tutorials/jsapi_profile/